# Xcode 4 won't update xib Interface on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, xcode4

I'm using Xcode 4.0.2 and im having this major issue. I can do what i want with my xib, delete all the views, move any objects around, or even delete the whole xib, but if i build & run my app on simulator it doesn't update the interface. It looks always the same, like it looked yesterday, but although i changed all the views it never updates the interface of the .app running on simulator. I have closed xcode a million times, deleted the app from simulator a million times, it's still the same |:  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning the product before rebuilding, and check that the xib is included in your target.

Alternatively, your project isn't using that .xib file at all and you've been editing the wrong one, or you decided at some point to build the interface in code instead and have since forgotten about it!

Comment: yes, I moved a view to another xib, and edited it there, but the ´pushModalViewController´ method was still refering to the old xib. I solved it before you answered, but your answer is still right! :P

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete it from Simulator manually: `/Users/yourUsername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/`